# Meteor Dropdown #each over a collection

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, materialize

I've been around this all day and i can't figure why my each cycle is not working. I'm trying to create a dropdown with some countries.

Helper

```
Template.register.helpers({
    countries: function(){
        return Country.find({ });
    },
});
```

View, template register

```
  <select id="country-select">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option> 
   {{#each countries}}
        <option value={{ name }}>{{ name }}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
```

I have records in the country collection

meteor:PRIMARY> db.country.find({ }).count() ->
4

The only options that the dropwdown displays is the placeholder.

I'm using mongol this is a country record

[image]

Comment: Does your `Country` object have a `name` key? What shows up in the HTML - an empty set of options or only the disabled one?

Comment: @MichelFloyd i edited the most. But i think it isnt even entering the each loop because i get 0 results even if i do something like  <option value="a">a</option> inside it

Comment: @MichelFloyd i tried out          {{#each countries}}
                            <p>{{name}}</p>
         {{/each}}

Comment: and it worked outside the select

Comment: Feels like a typo - name of helper doesn't match, name of template doesn't match. What you're doing *should* work.

Comment: @MichelFloyd i solved the problem with the last solution https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1469

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 <option disabled selected>Please select</option>
 {{#each countries}}
     <option>{{name}}</option>
 {{/each}}
```

It works here

Answer (score 1):

"The solution that worked for me is by calling the 'material_select' function after the options data has been loaded.

```
Template.[name].rendered = function() { this.autorun(function() { var optionsCursor = OptionsList.find().count(); if(optionsCursor > 0){ $('select').material_select(); } }); };"
```

from https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1469

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return Country.find().fetch()
```

in the helper

Thanks
Hope it helps